# Meaning of ほど in phrases like ご協力のほど , ご指導のほど, ご理解のほど (よろしくお願いします/ ありがとうございます) etc?

Tags: particle-ほど

Some Japanese friends explained to me that adding のほど just makes the speech sound more formal/polite and business-like, but the logic behind the use of ほど (meaning "degree" or "extent", as I know) in such cases still baffles me. 
Could someone pls explain? Many thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usage and function of:

> 「Noun + の + ほど」

is explained very nicely in  [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%A8%8B-573325#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88), which says:

> ４ （「…のほど」の形{かたち}で）断定{だんてい}を避{さ}け、表現{ひょうげん}をやわらげるのに用{もち}いる。

My TL of that would be:

> "In the form of 「…のほど」, it is used to soften the expression by avoiding a declaration."

Thus, this means that it sounds softer and slightly more sophisticated to say, for instance:

「ご協力{きょうりょく}**のほど**、よろしくお願{ねが}いいたします。」

than to say:

「ご協力、よろしくお願いいたします。」

because the latter can sound too direct.